# Filling missing values in Pandas DataFrame based on nearest location in another DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that resembles as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
date = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', freq='H', periods=4) 
locations = ["AA3", "AB1", "AD1", "AC0"] 
x = [5.5, 10.2, np.nan, 2.3, 11.2, np.nan, 2.1, 4.0, 6.1, np.nan, 20.3, 11.3, 4.9, 15.2, 21.3, np.nan] 

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x}) 
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([locations, date], names=['location', 'date']) 
df = df.sort_index() 
df
```

```
                                 x
location date                     
AA3      2020-01-01 00:00:00   5.5
         2020-01-01 01:00:00  10.2
         2020-01-01 02:00:00   NaN
         2020-01-01 03:00:00   2.3
AB1      2020-01-01 00:00:00  11.2
         2020-01-01 01:00:00   NaN
         2020-01-01 02:00:00   2.1
         2020-01-01 03:00:00   4.0
AC0      2020-01-01 00:00:00   4.9
         2020-01-01 01:00:00  15.2
         2020-01-01 02:00:00  21.3
         2020-01-01 03:00:00   NaN
AD1      2020-01-01 00:00:00   6.1
         2020-01-01 01:00:00   NaN
         2020-01-01 02:00:00  20.3
         2020-01-01 03:00:00  11.3
```

Index values are location codes and hours of the day. I want to fill missing values of column `x` with valid value of the same column from the nearest location on the same day and hour, where the proximity of each location to other locations is defined as

```
nearest = pd.DataFrame({"AA3": ["AA3", "AB1", "AD1", "AC0"],
                        "AB1": ["AB1", "AA3", "AC0", "AD1"],
                        "AD1": ["AD1", "AC0", "AB1", "AA3"],
                        "AC0": ["AC0", "AD1", "AA3", "AB1"]})
nearest
```

```
   AA3  AB1  AD1  AC0
0  AA3  AB1  AD1  AC0
1  AB1  AA3  AC0  AD1
2  AD1  AC0  AB1  AA3
3  AC0  AD1  AA1  AB1
```

In this dataset, column names are location codes and row values under each column indicate other locations in order of their proximity to the location whose name is give as column name.

If the nearest location also has missing value on the same day and hour, then I would take the value of the second nearest location on the same day and hour. If the second nearest location is missing, then the third nearest location on the same day and hour, and so on.

Desired output:

```
                                 x
location date                     
AA3      2020-01-01 00:00:00   5.5
         2020-01-01 01:00:00  10.2
         2020-01-01 02:00:00   2.1
         2020-01-01 03:00:00   2.3
AB1      2020-01-01 00:00:00  11.2
         2020-01-01 01:00:00  10.2
         2020-01-01 02:00:00   2.1
         2020-01-01 03:00:00   4.0
AC0      2020-01-01 00:00:00   4.9
         2020-01-01 01:00:00  15.2
         2020-01-01 02:00:00  21.3
         2020-01-01 03:00:00  11.3
AD1      2020-01-01 00:00:00   6.1
         2020-01-01 01:00:00  15.2
         2020-01-01 02:00:00  20.3
         2020-01-01 03:00:00  11.3
```

The following based on suggestions by [@kiona1018](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5972189/kiona1018) works as intended but it is slow.

```
def fillna_by_nearest(x: pd.Series, nn_data: pd.DataFrame):
    out = x.copy()
    for index, value in x.iteritems():
        if np.isnan(value) and (index[0] in nn_data.columns):
            location, date = index
            for near_location in nn_data[location]:
                if ((near_location, date) in x.index) and pd.notna(x.loc[near_location, date]):
                    out.loc[index] = x.loc[near_location, date]
                    break
    return out

fillna_by_nearest(df['x'], nearest)
```

Comment: What if the same day and hour of the nearest location is also NaN?

Comment: If the nearest location also has missing value, then the second nearest location but still on the same day and hour. If the second nearest location is missing, then the third nearest location on the same day and hour, and so on.

Comment: I cant think of a neater pandas/numpy execution for this. Have you considered a simple for-loop iteration instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Serial Lazer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751311/filling-missing-values-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-nearest-location-in-another#comment114486392_64751311) that there are no neater pandas/numpy executions for this. The requirement is a little bit complicated. In such a case, you should make your own function. An example is below.

```py
nearest = pd.DataFrame({"AA3": ["AA3", "AB1", "AD1", "AC0"],
                        "AB1": ["AB1", "AA3", "AC0", "AD1"],
                        "AD1": ["AD1", "AC0", "AB1", "AA3"],
                        "AC0": ["AC0", "AD1", "AA3", "AB1"]})


def fill_by_nearest(sr: pd.Series):
    if not np.isnan(sr['x']):
        return sr

    location = sr.name[0]
    date = sr.name[1]
    for near_location in nearest[location]:
        if not np.isnan(df.loc[near_location, date]['x']):
            sr['x'] = df.loc[near_location, date]['x']
            return sr
    return sr

df = df.apply(fill_by_nearest, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply function:

```
def find_nearest(row): 
    for item in list(nearest[row['location']]):
        if len(df[lambda x: (x['location']==item) & (x['date']==row['date']) &(~pd.isnull(x['x']))]):
            return df[lambda x: (x['location']==item) & (x['date']==row['date']) &(~pd.isnull(x['x']))].x.values[0]
    
df = df.reset_index()        
df = df.assign(x = lambda x: x.apply(find_nearest,axis=1))
```

#### Output:

```
   location                date     x
0       AA3 2020-01-01 00:00:00   5.5
1       AA3 2020-01-01 01:00:00  10.2
2       AA3 2020-01-01 02:00:00   2.1
3       AA3 2020-01-01 03:00:00   2.3
4       AB1 2020-01-01 00:00:00  11.2
5       AB1 2020-01-01 01:00:00  10.2
6       AB1 2020-01-01 02:00:00   2.1
7       AB1 2020-01-01 03:00:00   4.0
8       AC0 2020-01-01 00:00:00   4.9
9       AC0 2020-01-01 01:00:00  15.2
10      AC0 2020-01-01 02:00:00  21.3
11      AC0 2020-01-01 03:00:00  11.3
12      AD1 2020-01-01 00:00:00   6.1
13      AD1 2020-01-01 01:00:00  15.2
14      AD1 2020-01-01 02:00:00  20.3
15      AD1 2020-01-01 03:00:00  11.3
```